# Saving in local storage

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, local-storage, faker

I'm doing a DnD table with react and I need to save data into local storage ( cards dropped onto "room-info" div).

Tried using usestate to track dropped cards into array and using useeffect hook for local data storing.

I'm new to react, so maybe someone could help me to tweak this code?

```
  handleDrop,
  handleCardRemove,
  dragStart,
} from "./components/dragAndDrop";

function App() {
  const [selectedRoom, setSelectedRoom] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem("selectedRoom")
  );

 
  const [droppedCards, setDroppedCards] = useState(() => {
    const storedDroppedCards = localStorage.getItem("droppedCards");
    return storedDroppedCards ? JSON.parse(storedDroppedCards) : [];
  });

  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  const generateCards = () => {
    const newCards = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      const cardId = faker.random.uuid();
      const cardContent = faker.name.findName();
      newCards.push(
        <Card
          key={cardId}
          id={cardId}
          className="card"
          draggable="true"
          onDoubleClick={() => handleCardRemove(cardId)}
          onDragStart={dragStart}
        >
          {cardContent}
        </Card>
      );
    }
    setCards((prevCards) => [...prevCards, ...newCards]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("selectedRoom", selectedRoom);
  }, [selectedRoom]);

  // Step 3: Handle dropping of cards onto selected room
  const handleCardDrop = (cardId) => {
    setDroppedCards((prevDroppedCards) => {
      const updatedDroppedCards = [...prevDroppedCards, cardId];
      localStorage.setItem("droppedCards", JSON.stringify(updatedDroppedCards));
      return updatedDroppedCards;
    });

    // Step 3b: Save droppedCards to local storage
    localStorage.setItem(
      "droppedCards",
      JSON.stringify([...droppedCards, cardId])
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedDroppedCards = localStorage.getItem("droppedCards");
    if (storedDroppedCards) {
      setDroppedCards(JSON.parse(storedDroppedCards));
    }
  }, [setDroppedCards]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <main className="flexbox">
        <Board id="board-rooms" className="board-rooms" draggable="false">
          <div className="board-label">Rooms</div>
          <Rooms
            id="rooms"
            className="rooms"
            selectedRoom={selectedRoom}
            items={rooms.map((room) => ({
              ...room,
              onClick: () => setSelectedRoom(room.name),
            }))}
          />
        </Board>

        <Board id="board-1" className="board-info">
          <div className="board-label">Information</div>
          {selectedRoom && (
            <div className="room-info">
              <p>
                <b>{selectedRoom}</b>
              </p>
            </div>
          )}
        </Board>
        <Board
          id="board-2"
          className="board-guests"
          onDrop={(e) => handleDrop(e, handleCardDrop)}
          onDragOver={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
        >
          <div className="board-label">Guests</div>
          {cards}
          <button onClick={generateCards}>Generate names</button>
        </Board>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Maybe someone could help me fix this issue or atleast give some useful hints ?

Comment: Typically youd only store the ID's of the cards and not the whole card. But I see here your cards are generated locally with random UUID which precludes this. They would need a stable ID. Is this some intermediate state whilst you work on your app? Do you plan on having this data from the server or something and the faker stuff is a temporary mock?

Comment: It's a temporary mock. I'm thinking of just putting them into a simple array. Maybe this would make it easier to track with useState and cardId.

Comment: Right, for the mock to be valid, you need the mock to have consistent ID's between reloads. You can get around this without having a static array by adding a seed to fakerjs such that it generates the same set of random data each time. You can do it using `faker.seed(100)` for example. Call this at the top of the file outside of the component. This makes faker deterministic at least in synchronous scenarios like yours.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example using React DnD to write dropped cards to the local storage when they are dropped into a "room-info" div:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDrop } from "react-dnd";

const App = () => {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  const handleDrop = (item, monitor) => {
    const droppedCard = item.card;
    setCards([...cards, droppedCard]);

    // Write the new cards to local storage
    localStorage.setItem("droppedCards", JSON.stringify([...cards, droppedCard]));
  };

  const [{ isOver }, drop] = useDrop({
    accept: "card",
    drop: handleDrop,
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
    }),
  });

  // On component mount, retrieve the saved cards from local storage
  useEffect(() => {
    const savedCards = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("droppedCards"));
    if (savedCards) {
      setCards(savedCards);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="room">
      <div className="room-info" ref={drop}>
        <p>Drop cards here to update local storage:</p>
        {cards.map((card) => (
          <div key={card.id}>{card.name}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

It won't do everything you want it to do but I reckon it's a good place to start creating the skeleton component.

1. Define the handleDrop function, which is called whenever a card is dropped into the "room-info" div. This function updates the cards state by adding the dropped card to the existing array of cards using the `setCards` method. It also writes the new array of cards to local storage using the localStorage.setItem method
2. Define the drop target using the useDrop hook
3. On component mount, we retrieve the saved cards from local storage using the localStorage.getItem method and update the cards state with the retrieved array of cards using the setCards method.
4. Render the "room-info" div and pass the drop ref to it so that it becomes a drop target. We also render the list of cards currently in the cards state using the map function.

To conclude, whenever a card is dropped into the "room-info" div, the handleDrop function will be called, which will update the cards state to include the dropped card and write the new array of cards to local storage. On component mount, the saved cards are retrieved from local storage and used to init the cards state.